# Testing for Title Not Working with rspec/capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I'm building my first webapp on Rails 3.0.10 and trying to right my title tests in my Pages_Controller_Spec as I learned from the ruby on rails tutorial book, however even though the titles are correct in the browser, the tests are failing. I have installed Capybara, but haven't used it yet - is that potentially interfering?

You'll see it's very basic right now, but I want to start from the ground up with a solid testing suite. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is my spec: (The simple "should be_success pass fine)

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PagesController do

  render_views

   describe "GET 'home'" do

    it "should be successful" do
      get 'home'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'home'
      response.should have_selector("title", 
                  :content => "Home")
    end

  end

  describe "GET 'contact'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'contact'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'contact'
      response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Contact")
    end

  end

end
```

I'm rendering the title in the application layout like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title><%= @title %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is how I'm setting the instance variable:

```
<% @title = "Home" %>

<h1>Pages#home</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/pages/home.html.erb</p>
```

EDIT: Here is the test output

```
Failures:

1) PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title
Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("title",
expected css "title" to return something
# ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) PagesController GET 'contact' should have the right title
Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Contact")
expected css "title" to return something
# ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:29:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.14245 seconds
4 examples, 2 failures
```

EDIT 2: Adding what puts response.body

```
Running: spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb
.<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Home</title>

  <script src="/javascripts/prototype.js?1315409404" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/effects.js?1315409404" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/dragdrop.js?1315409404" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/controls.js?1315409404" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/rails.js?1315409404" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/application.js?1315409404" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>


<h1>Pages#home</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/pages/home.html.erb</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the output of the test?

Comment: edited the post to include that information.

Comment: Could it be that the `has_selector?` method only works for visible content? Have you tried to use `page.html.should match '<title>Home</title>'` or something like that?

Comment: well, I thought having 'render_views' at the top make it work on visible content like that. Perhaps this changed at some point?

Comment: What does "puts response.body" show?

Comment: I've added in what puts response.body - it's def rendering the view I guess! And the title is right there...seems like I'm fretting over such a small thing...but I wanna get this right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out I didn't have WebRat installed as a gem. I guess this came from me taking my testing gems from railscast and using some of the tests I learned in the Hartl tutorial.

Thanks for the help!